# How to upload image with jQuery re-size and crop (jrac)

Tags: php, jquery, upload, resize, crop

Help me please, I need to use [jrac](https://github.com/trepmag/jrac) or some jQuery plugins then upload it using PHP.  Using jrac I can only re-size and crop, I'm stuck in uploading.

Comment: I wish there was a "what have you tried so far" button tight next to the "add comment" button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You firstly have to resize it according to the new width nad height than pick  the cropped portion of new image.
I have code. Do you still need this?